# Comparing numbers between 1st array and 2nd array

Tags: java, arrays, integer, comparison

I'm having problem in comparing numbers.

So I'm trying to compare 2 arrays each with 6 different numbers. If there are same numbers in those two elements, the users score will be added.

Example: First Array: 1, 17, 14, 38 ,6,24
         Second Array: 22, 3, 7, 1, 42, 9

The 1st and the 2nd array both have the number 1, so the score will be added.

My problem is how to compare them?

here's the code for the 1st and 2nd Array:

```
for (int x = 0;x<6;x++)
        {
            A[x] = (int) (1+Math.random()*counter);

            for (int y=0;y<x;y++)
            {
                if (A[x]==A[y])
                x--;
            }
        }
```

That's also the same code for the 2nd array.

I have try this code to compare the two:

```
for (x=0;x<6;x++)
{
     if (A[x]==B[x])
     {
        score++;
     }
}
```

Now I figured out what the problem is. My code doesn't compare all of the integers in the 1st and 2nd array.

Can you please give me an idea on how to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You need two loops to check values. Other wise it will only compare values of same index.

Try this:

```
for (int x=0;x<A.length;x++){
    for (int y=0;y<B.length;y++){
    if (A[x]==B[y])
        score++;
    }
}
```

Use `A.length` instead if `x<6`, it will avoid hardcoding.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int x = 0;x<6;x++)
        {
            A[x] = (int) (1+Math.random()*counter);

            for (int y=0;y<x;y++)
            {
                if (A[x].equals(A[y]))
                x--;
            }
        }
```

Try this but i have't test it.